# Unexpected indent for all bold paragraphs after first

Tags: indentation

After the first lines in a paragraph I have an unexpected indent. My question here is why is it there and how can I avoid it?

```
My .tex file is like this:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof]{scrbook}
.........

\chapter{chapterTitle}

\section{sectionTitle}

\textbf{part1}: +5 xyz\\*
\textit{description}\\*

\textbf{part2}: comments\\
\textit{description}\\

\textbf{part3}: comments

......
```

Part 1 has no indenting, but part 2 and part 3 each start with the bold parts indented (if something from teh comments or description (description as a whole are not indented thus only the bold part is indented each) is in a new line then it is not indented each.

Comment: because you start new paragraphs, and paragraphs apart the first paragraph of a section are indented. if you don't want  them to be indented use `\noindent`, i.e., `\noindent\textbf{part2}...`

Comment: An empty line signifies a paragraph break, and the default way to mark new paragraphs is to start a new line and indent the first line of the paragraph. Generally you should (almost) never have to use `\\ ` in the text, perhaps section **3.10 Paragraph markup** of the KOMA-script manual is of interest.

Comment: Just in case you want to remove **all** indents and use blank lines instead, you might try to add `parskip=full` to the KOMA-script options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the bold lines are first lines in new paragraphs. There is no indent in the first paragraph of a section, and there is indent in the following.

I would use `\subsection` or `\subsection*`, this will do what you want.

Alternatively put `\noindent` before the bold parts.